# Managment Network: provide wireless access to 3 campus

Tags: wireless, design, architecture

During an interview I was asked to provide a basic outline of a project managment for a network position. The **objective** was to provide wireless access to 3 campus (let's say each of 1000 people) that were already connected to a backbone.

If you were asked to define some variables to better understand the project and to provide:

- a list of all devices that needs to be purchased
- a planning in form of a GANTT and WBS
- a list of all people needed for this
- budget estimation and assignment over time/people

How would you approach this pratically ? I understand that this question is a bit vague, but if the answer can provide a "model" project that would be helpful to solve similar assignments

Comment: This question is overly broad, and the answers to the question would be opinion-based. You should read up in the [help] on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @Ron: I know that, and I have even specified in the question. The problem is that I faced this exact question... Which details should be included/excluded? I can try to make it more specific by guessing requirements if you can help me

Comment: You have some problems. This question is really about project management, so maybe you should ask on http://pm.stackexchange.com/ instead. Questions which lead to opinion-based answers are off-topic here.

Comment: I don't think it's a P.M. question per se. It's related to how to provide wireless access to 3 campus, I think an answer providing general guidelines would be perfectly in topic here. Thank you anyway for your help

Comment: What specifically are you asking? Do you want us to design the network, recommending products, costs, etc. as you list? Asking for an approach is far too broad and opinion based, and recommendations are off-topic. I don't really understand what you want that would be on-topic.

Comment: Exactly: design the network, recommending products, costs, etc. That would be a great start

Comment: That's not what we do here.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who interviews candidates, I can tell you that the specifics of the the network design are the least important part of the answer.

What the interviewer wants to know is how you would organize and execute the project.  He/she wants to know if you can identify the missing information (lots) and identify the steps get it.  He wants to know if you can identify the resources you need to to get the job done.  Remember, they want a basic outline of the project.

The interviewer was laying a trap to see if you'd dive into the technical design instead of all the project issues.  Unfortunately, it seems you took the bait.

Comment: Thanks Ron, very helpful, If i got the reputation I would upvote you. Anyway could you provide more details about your answer? For example, which do you think are the missing information? Which are the steps? Thanks a lot +1